# Rails use destroy soft_destroy, how to update deleted_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Excuse me,
I am using soft_destroy to delete my data, and then I want to fix the deleted_by data when I try to delete it.
So I used before_destroy in the model to do the processing.
But it seems to have no effect.
How can I do? Please tell me. thanks

Controller

```
def destroy
   @project.soft_destroy
   head :no_content
end
```

Model

```
before_destroy :deleted_by


private

def deleted_by
  self.deleted_by = 101
end
```

After these executions, deleted_by does not become 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in controller

```
 before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]
 before_action :deleted_by, only: [:destroy]

private
def set_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def deleted_by
  @project.deleted_by = 101
end
```

Comment: thanks !   sorry late late reply you.
this methods is great!

Answer (score 0):

Try on callback before_update because the record is not actually getting deleted.